# Using Alternative Distance Metrics like Mahalanobis with DBSCAN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use `Mahalanobis` distance in combination with `DBSCAN`.

For `NearestNeighbors` you can pass `metric='mahalanobis'` and `metric_params={'V': np.cov(X)}` for using `Mahalanobis` distance.

```
DBSCAN(eps=0.15, min_samples=8, metric='...', algorithm='brute', leaf_size=30, n_jobs=-1)
```

But how to do it with `DBSCAN`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers above didn't work for me at the beginning of 2021. Today, you don't pass a distance object, instead you pass a dictionary with the mahalanobis covariance parameter.

The example above would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

X, y = make_classification()

sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(eps=0.15, min_samples=8, metric='mahalanobis', metric_params={'V':np.cov(X)}, algorithm='brute', leaf_size=30, n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: helped [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68603175/15893581) - *metric_params={'VI':np.cov(X)}*

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to create a metric via, e.g. `DistanceMetric`.

For example, you could use:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

X, y = make_classification()
metric = DistanceMetric.get_metric('mahalanobis', V=np.cov(X))

sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(eps=0.15, min_samples=8, metric=metric, 
                       algorithm='brute', leaf_size=30, n_jobs=-1)
```